# Looking for example of asp.net core web app calling an api both using AAD B2C

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I am fairly new to development and I am looking for an example of an asp.net core web app calling an .net core api both protected by the same Azure AD B2C.
I found examples with 2.2 but I was not able to adapt them to core 3.1.

Thanks

Comment: What errors do you face? Have you tried creating the project with 2.2 and then migrstig it to 3.1?

Comment: I got errors saying that xxx is obsolete and need to check for breaking changes in msal v3 and v4, unfortunately it is beyond my capabilities to understand all of the modification to be made, when able to correct one (maybe or maybe not, not sure I know what I am doing), another pops up.